# PIL Image refusing to save file

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to write a simple script using Pillow's image module to convert an image from RGBA to RGB, a very simple task. But, the image fails to safe, what's going on?

Here's the whole .py file. (Both the .py and the src_images folder are in the same directory.)

```
from PIL import Image

image_debug = Image.open('src_images/image1.png')

image_debug = image_debug.convert('RGB')
image_debug.save = ('converted_image.png')
image_debug = Image.open('converted_image.png')
```

When running, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/armin/PycharmProjects/dynamic-wal-changer/tests/DEBUG.py", line 7, in <module>
    image_debug = Image.open('converted_image.png')
  File "/home/armin/PycharmProjects/dynamic-wal-changer/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2580, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'converted_image.png'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It's refusing to save the image for whatever reason, any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: the input image is opened on the 3rd line (src_images/image1.png), the error occurs on line 7 where it tries to open the final converted image that was saved in the line above, but fails because line 6 did not save the file anywhere (the issue). I have no idea why line 6 doesn't save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line

```
image_debug.save = ('converted_image.png')
```

should be

```
image_debug.save('converted_image.png')
```